# What is the equivalent Treeview.OnChange event in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, events, treeview

I have treeview control on a winform and need to implement onChange event for it. However, it looks like it doesn't have one and only has onChangeUI.

If the treeview doesn't support onChange event, what is its equivalent in .NET.

I've searched MSDN Library and didn't find any information.

**Update:** a side note I am converting win32 program for .net.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you looked at the `SelectedNodeChanged` event?

Comment: @Kane, that's for the ASP.NET tree control, not the Windows Forms one. digitalanalog, what kind of change event are you looking for? Selection change? Item label change? Something else?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks for picking up on doh! moment for today. There are lots of `BeforeXXX` and `AfterXXX` events to choose from which one do you need?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, very similar to what kane mentioned. Basically any node change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for selection change is a little limited in the Windows Forms TreeView control.

Basically, there is a pair of events ([BeforeSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforeselect.aspx) and [AfterSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect.aspx)) that allow you to react when a tree node is selected. `BeforeSelect` allows you to cancel the new selection, `AfterSelect` does not (because it occurs after the new selection has been committed).

However, none of these events are triggered when a node is *unselected*. To detect that case, you'll have to handle the generic [MouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup.aspx) event and check the [IsSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.isselected.aspx) property of the clicked node to get the actual selection state.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common restriction in the wrapper classes that wrap native Windows controls.  Which only generate notifications for things that you cannot know about.  Like anything that the user can do that affects the control.  It omits notifications for things that *you* do, with the underlying philosophy that you don't have to be reminded about something you already know.

Which is certainly the case for TreeView, the user cannot add any nodes.  Only you can.  Same thing for the text displayed in the nodes.  No event to tell you the text changed.  Except in the very specific case when the user edits the node, AfterLabelEdit event.

You can derive your own class from TreeView and add a Change event and OnChange() method that fires it.  It is up to you to write the code to call the method.  Beware that this is difficult to do reliably, the TreeNodeCollection class doesn't have virtual methods so you cannot override them to detect the client code changing nodes.  You are actually better off not writing that code and simply generate an internal event in the form in any method that modifies the TreeView content.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer, but I believe the restriction in question is not native to Windows, as the good, old-fashioned treeview control had [TVN_SELCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773547.aspx) and [TVN_SELCHANGED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773544.aspx), both of which would fire when a tree node was unselected as well as selected. Sure, multiple selection was yours to implement back then, but IMHO even that feature arguably does not justify the hoops we have to jump through now to handle simple selection events :)